# Wordpress - one installation for multiple web sites

Tags: wordpress

I have multiple website with different databases and different hosts. Is there a way to have one dashboard for all sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer:
**YES** - You can create your own so called [Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network).
But **NO** not on **different Hosts** and **not** with **different** databases!

Add `define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );` to your `wp-config.php`.

This will enable you the option **Network Setup** under the MenuItem **Tools** and it will guide you throw the whole setup process.

---

I did this for you for testing and of course for all the other which will come here:

http://q29721173.dominikangerer.com/wp-admin

**Username**: stackoverflow
**Password**: Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

**YES** you can use [wordpress multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network). Its an feature from wordpress where you can **group websites and control them from one control panel**. From dashboard you have a dropdown from where you can navigate between different sites. You can host different plugins and templates on different websites.

Answer (score 0):

**NO**, you cannot have a dashboard for different databases and different hosts.

A [Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) works with just one database.